# Send Access Attachment Field as a CDO Attachment with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, email-attachments, cdo.message

I have the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Command27_Click()

Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("M:\Instructor Letter Templates (Typical).htm")
InstructorText = f.ReadAll
f.Close
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Dim strWhere As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
sql = "SELECT Classes.ClassID, Grade.GradeID, Instructors.RiosaladoEmail, students.sLastName, students.sFirstName, Grade.Form, Grade.Printout FROM students INNER JOIN (Classes INNER JOIN (Instructors INNER JOIN Grade ON Instructors.InstructorID = Grade.[Instructor]) ON Classes.ClassID = Grade.ClassID) ON students.StudentID = Grade.StudentID WHERE Grade.DateProcessed=Date()"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rs.EOF

Dim Class As String
Dim Grade As String
Dim Email As String
Dim Today As String
Dim sLast As String
Dim sFirst As String
Dim Form As String


Class = rs("ClassID")
Grade = rs("GradeID")
Email = rs("RiosaladoEmail")
sLast = rs("sLastName")
sFirst = rs("sFirstName")
Form = rs("Form")

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
Const cdoAnonymous = 0
Const cdoBasic = 1
Const cdoNTLM = 2

Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
cdomsg.Subject = sLast & "," & sFirst & Class & Chr(32) & Form
cdomsg.FROM = "<myemail>"
cdomsg.To = Email
cdomsg.HTMLBody = InstructorText
cdomsg.AddAttachment


cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "MyEmail"

'Your password on the SMTP server
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "MyPW"

'Server port (typically 25)
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Update

cdomsg.Send

rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

In the query, the field "Grade.Printout" is an Access attachment field with a file attached to it ... in a table.

I want to use this field with cdomsg.AddAttachment ... I know that if I use "cdomsg.AddAttachment ("")" that I can attach a specific file path ... but I want to use the attachment field within Access.

Or is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDO AddAttachment method needs to be given the location of the file to be attached, and it doesn't have any way of recognizing a reference to an Access table/field. Therefore you'll need to save the Access attachment to a temporary location using the [SaveToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191852.aspx) method of an Access DAO `Field2` object, and then pass the path of that file to the CDO AddAttachment method.